# Array parameter, empty by default

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, railo

I want to pass an optional array parameter to a function. If the parameter is not provided, the array should be empty.
I tried the following:

```
<cfargument name="time_blocks" type="array" required="false" default="[]">
```

But I get the following error:

```
invalid call of the function CreateRateBlock
14th Argument (time_blocks) is of invalid type, can't cast String [] to a value of type [array]
```

I also tried this:

```
<cfargument name="time_blocks" type="array" required="false" default="">
```

In this case, the error is almost the same:

```
invalid call of the function CreateRateBlock
14th Argument (time_blocks) is of invalid type, can't cast String [] to a value of type [array]
```

I also tried removing the default attribute, but in that case the value of `time_blocks` is null.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with [] without quotes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[]` does not work because it is just a string of 2 chars `"[]"`.

`#[]#` technically should work, but older CF is not smart enough.  So use:

```
<cfargument name="time_blocks" type="array" required="false" default="#arrayNew(1)#">
```

Comment: `#[]#` works on cflive.net's CF 9 / Railo 4. `<cfparam name="test" default="#[]#">
  
  <cfdump var="#test#">`

Comment: Yeah I don't think that's been a problem since CF8, so unless they're running CF8 and actually *have* that problem, using `#[]#` is a better answer, I think

Answer (score 7):

Change `[]` to `#[]#`. You're currently trying to give it the literal value `"[]"`.